# Obtaining an Azure Maps Access Token using a Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-maps

I'm trying to obtain a Azure Maps Token using a Azure Function based on the following documentation.

[How to secure a single-page web application with non-interactive sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-secure-spa-app)

Does anyone know how to create a Azure Maps Client using .NET similar to this?

[AzureMapsManagement client library for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/arm-maps-readme?view=azure-node-latest)

Answer (score -1):

They just released a .NET client library yesterday. You can find it here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/maps

For example, if you wanted to use the search API, you would authenticate
in a similar manner to the JavaScript client library:

```
AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential("<My Subscription Key>");
MapsSearchClient client = new MapsSearchClient(credential);
```

Here is some documentation on this client library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-dev-guide-csharp-sdk

For token base authentication you can use the `Azure.Core.TokenCredential` class. A good article on the different ways to do this can be found here: https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/defaultazurecredential-from-azure-sdk/ (not putting code in stackoverflow as there are a lot of different ways depending on your scenario).